# Xpath to select based on attribute value not working in PHP as expected

Tags: php, xpath

The code works well if it is "//div" or "//html". The moment I use "//*[@class='hit']", "//div[@class='hit']" or '//*[@class="hit"]', it does not select the element I need.

This is the code:

```
$xpath = "//div";
$data = file_get_contents("https://www.hachi.tech/searching?q=&hPP=144&idx=instant_product_price_asc&p=0&is_v=1");
d($data);
//d() is a custom function that works like var_dump
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($data);
$xpatho = new DOMXpath($doc);
$elementsn = $xpatho->query($xpath);

d($xpath);
d($elementsn->length);
//d() is a custom function that works like var_dump
```

When I dumped $data, I got this:
https://justpaste.it/38v46
(the text is very long so I pasted in a separate link).

There is clearly a div element with class="hit" in the html (you can do a search). Search for:

```
<div class="hit" style="min-height:258px;">
```

I can only think of malformed HTML, in which case what can I do in general to check (and fix!) the HTML first before passing it for selection?

Comment: Please do not abandon questions that you post.  If the answer has resolved your question, please accept it.  If it is not resolved, please correspond with the answerer to progress toward an acceptable resolution.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access that `div` directly because it is not in the DOM; it is inside a `script` element and thus treated as text. It gets added to the DOM once the page loads, via this code:

```
a.addWidget(instantsearch.widgets.hits({container:"#hits",hitsPerPage: showperpage,templates:{item: document.querySelector("#hit-template").innerHTML ,empty: document.querySelector("#no-results-template").innerHTML }}));
```

You can find the contents of the `script` tag with this code:

```
$xpatho = new DOMXPath($dom);
$elementsn = $xpatho->query("//*[contains(text(), 'div class=\"hit\"')]");
var_dump($elementsn);
echo htmlspecialchars($elementsn->item(0)->nodeValue);
```

Output:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"> <div class="hit" style="min-height:258px;"> <div class="thumbnail"> <div class="stay-image"> <div class="space-overlay hide" id="{{item_id}}"> <a href="https://www.hachi.tech/product/{{{item_id}}}/{{{item_url_desc}}}"><img src="https://cdn.hachi.tech/assets/images/product_images_thumb/{{image}}" alt="{{item_desc}}" class="img-responsive"/> <div class="caption"> <h5 class="product-title"><a style="-webkit-line-clamp: 3;max-height: 50px;" href="https://www.hachi.tech/product/{{{item_id}}}/{{{item_url_desc}}}">{{{_highlightResult.item_desc.value}}} <div class="prod-rating" id="R{{{item_id}}}"> <span class="text-red mbr-price"><span class="text-red mbr-price hidden-xs">ValueClub {{{display_final_price}}} <br class="dp_rebate"><span class="dp_rebate text-red product-price">{{{rebate}}} <p> <span class="reg-price"> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm" style='color:black'>{{strikeoff}} <div class="positionBtns"> {{#color_display}} <a class="hidden-xs hidden-sm" id="{{item_id}}" href="https://www.hachi.tech/product/{{{item_id}}}/{{{item_url_desc}}}"><span class="colours-special">{{color_display}} {{/color_display}} {{#special_display}} <a class="hidden-xs hidden-sm" id="{{item_id}}" href="https://www.hachi.tech/product/{{{item_id}}}/{{{item_url_desc}}}"><span class="colours-special">{{special_display}} {{/special_display}} <span class="colours-special publish_inv_check hide " style="color: #EE1C24;" id="{{item_id}}">Sold Out
```

but if you want to directly access that `div`, you will need to use a headless browser such as Selenium.